# Animation end at half time duration

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I am using an animator but I have a big problem testing on Android API 22

```
ValueAnimator mAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(3000);
mAnimation.setDuration(3000);
```

This mAnimation end at about 1500ms (about half of duration)
I don't understand why....

I have the same result if I use ObjectAnimator.

Testing on 2 devices having API 22, the result is different.
In 1, animation is correct
In 2, animation end at half duration time

How is possible ?

I post code with ObjectAnimator too (the animation end at about 9000ms):

```
mAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(seek_bar, "progress", 18000);
mAnimation.setDuration(18000);
mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
mAnimation.setupStartValues();
mAnimation.start();
```

**SOLVED**
Check Developer Option (settings menu). Scale animation was set to 0.5x (I don't know why...). So now at 1x all works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You should post the whole animation code and maybe the layout files. You might have some computing issues

Comment: The animation code is complete, I don't have other. The same for layout.

Comment: can you check the other device's Animator Duration scale from developer options. Make sure it is set to 1x

Comment: Ok, I will check. But if for example, this is set to 2x, how can I manage by app ? I need to know if the scale is right because the if not, my application will not works